# Answer from Function is incorrect

Tags: c++, trigonometry

The answer of this function is returned into the main function of the program, and that works fine. The issue is that any value where the cosine should be 0, it turns out to give a weird irrational number (something like 1.30431912*10^-13). So, 90, 450, and so on, all turn out irrational answers. What's the matter?

```
  float cosineDegrees() {
        string i;
        double iDouble;

        cout << "Give me a number to find the value of degrees in. ";
        getline(cin, i);

        iDouble = stod(i);

        double PI = 3.14159265359;

        float answer = cos((PI/180)*iDouble);

        return answer;


    }
```

Comment: pi isn't exactly 3.14159265359, is it?

Comment: 1.30431912*10^-13 is not irrational. It's perfectly rational, but very close to zero. It's as close to zero as you're likely to get. See also [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating-point math has finite precision. Your `(PI/180)*iDouble` value is about 1.30E-13 radian away from 90 degrees.

Comment: So that's as about as precise I can really get things, then?

Comment: I think it would help the OP to also present a solution, or an explanation of how to craft one.

Comment: @stijn: The question appears to ask for an explanation, not a solution, and thast's non-trivial anyway. cos(45) is not going to return √2.

Answer (score 1):

If you lock Pi to a limited precision you can't expect your 'answer' to be more precise. 10^-13 is basically zero in fact, and it's not 'irrational.' Everything is rational in a computer.

Comment: Well, `std::complex` is not rational ;)